# Which of the following codes will run in the same process of the current shell

Tags: bash, process

A. `{ echo "Hello World"; } >outputfile`

B. `( echo "Hello World" ) >outputfile`

C. `./anothershell.sh`

D. `/bin/echo "Hello World"`

Which is right? And what kind of command can run in the same process of the current shell?

Comment: I think both `A` and `B`

Comment: But hard to prove it. The command `echo` ends quickly and difficult to catch its process

Comment: Additionally, E. `. ./anothershell.sh` would execute in the current shell.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have asked a couple times about how to prove it. You use environment variable setting as a probe:

```
export testvar=nope
{ echo "Hello World"; export testvar=yep; } >outputfile
printenv testvar
```

writes `yep`

```
export testvar=nope
( echo "Hello World"; export testvar=yep; ) >outputfile
printenv testvar
```

writes `nope`

You'll need to edit your script in (C) and compile a modified echo for (D), but then the corresponding constructs for them will also write `nope`. This shows explicitly that only case (A) and [glennjackman's case (E) from the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/189911/which-of-the-following-codes-will-run-in-the-same-process-of-the-current-shell#comment317168_189911) run in the same process.

Answer (score 14):

Only A will run within the process of the current shell.

B will run in a subshell because you asked for a subshell by using paranehteses.

C and D will both run outside of the current shell process because they are invocations of external commands.

Comment: Do you have a way to verify this?

Comment: @Miline, https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping

Comment: @Miline you could use `strace` under Linux or `truss` under Solaris, for example. Why? Did you expect a different answer?

Comment: I was just curious to find a way to verify it.

Comment: When I verify A using `strace ( echo "Hello World" ) >outputfile`, I met an error. Could you tell me howto deal with it? thks @Celada

Comment: @HHan You need to attach strace to the original shell. You could put all the lines in a script and then strace a shell running the script, or attach strace to your running shell with strace -p from a separate terminal.

Answer (score 4):

One distinction you may be missing is that B will fork (so it's another process), but it doesn't actually exec (it's a copy of the same shell, it doesn't go and find /bin/sh and re-run initializers etc). And there are special rules ($$ is the pid of the original shell, for example).